# Get all themes in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I get all themes from `App_Themes` in my web project?

I would like to get all of it and put in dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that will give you list of theme names :

```
var path = Server.MaPPath("~/App_Themes");
var list = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                    .Select(folder => new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name)
                    .ToList();
```